# NFT token undefined

Tags: ether, nft, polygon, lazy-mint

I'm developing a lazy minting website, which is deployed to Mumbai network. But the token id return undefined.

**Minter.jsx**

```
async function mintNFT({ contract, ownerAddress, provider, gasPrice, setStatus, image, name, description }) {

  // First we use the nft.storage client library to add the image and metadata to IPFS / Filecoin
  const client = new NFTStorage({ token: NFT_STORAGE_KEY });
  setStatus("Uploading to nft.storage...")
  const metadata = await client.store({
    name,
    description,
    image,
  });
  setStatus(`Upload complete! Minting token with metadata URI: ${metadata.url}`);

  // the returned metadata.url has the IPFS URI we want to add.
  // our smart contract already prefixes URIs with "ipfs://", so we remove it before calling the `mintToken` function
  const metadataURI = metadata.url.replace(/^ipfs:\/\//, "");
  console.log("MetaData URI "+metadataURI);  

  // get metadata hash replace 1
  const lazyMinter = new LazyMinter({ contract, signer: ownerAddress })
  const voucher =  lazyMinter.createVoucher(1, metadata.url)
  console.log("Token Id  "+voucher.tokenId);
  return voucher.tokenId;
}
```

**LazyMinter.js**

```
/**
   * Creates a new NFTVoucher object and signs it using this LazyMinter's signing key.
   * 
   * @param {ethers.BigNumber | number} tokenId the id of the un-minted NFT
   * @param {string} uri the metadata URI to associate with this NFT
   * @param {ethers.BigNumber | number} minPrice the minimum price (in wei) that the creator will accept to redeem this NFT. defaults to zero
   * 
   * @returns {NFTVoucher}
   */
  async createVoucher(tokenId, uri, minPrice = 0) {
    const voucher = { tokenId, uri, minPrice }
    const domain = await this._signingDomain()
    const types = {
      NFTVoucher: [
        { name: "tokenId", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "minPrice", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "uri", type: "string" },
      ]
    }
    const signature = await this.signer._signTypedData(domain, types, voucher);
    return {
      ...voucher,
      signature,
    }
  }

  /**
   * @private
   * @returns {object} the EIP-721 signing domain, tied to the chainId of the signer
   */
  async _signingDomain() {
    if (this._domain != null) {
      console.log("it s not null");
      return this._domain
    }
    console.log("The contract is " + this.contract);
    console.log("chain id " + this.contract.getChainID())
    const chainId = await this.contract.getChainID();
    console.log("chain id " + chainId);
    this._domain = {
      name: SIGNING_DOMAIN_NAME,
      version: SIGNING_DOMAIN_VERSION,
      verifyingContract: this.contract.address,
      chainId,
    }
    return this._domain
  }
```

Console output

[image]

**Edit**

After added `async` in front, I get this error in frontend:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): call revert exception (method="getChainID()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.2.0)
```

This is the console log displayed in `_signingDomain` method.

```
The contract is [object Object]
LazyMinter.js:70 chain id [object Promise]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const voucher =  lazyMinter.createVoucher(1, metadata.url)`

Here you are calling an asynchronous function without telling the thread to wait for the result.

`const voucher =  await lazyMinter.createVoucher(1, metadata.url)`

As you have added a couple of awaits in the code, the above solution would be the simplest. Also you can use a [promise](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sunz7/ce2291d4277066b20f56130853d88cab/raw/f01bd4a4391c25070d6a9537228ba8fa5d99672e/promise-create-2.js) or [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/sample) based solution.

Comment: after I add `await` in front, it not printing `Token Id`. Seems like keep waiting for something to return.

Comment: it might be an issue with one or both of the async functions, there are no errors?
can you check whether `await this.contract.getChainID()` and  ` await this.signer._signTypedData(domain, types, voucher)` with console logs. also, the signer code is not visible hope it looks something like `const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)`

Comment: thanks for the tips! I have edited my post.

Comment: Is it because the `contract` was wrong?

Comment: Btw, you don't need to get the chain Id using the contract right? also is there a function called getChainID() in your solidity contract?

Comment: `await ethers.provider.getNetwork()` gives you the network details and `(await ethers.provider.getNetwork())?.chainId` will give you the selected chainId

```const chainId =  (await ethers.provider.getNetwork())?.chainId;```

Comment: Thanks ! I just replace chain id as `80001` first since it deployed to Mumbai.

Comment: For this line  `await lazyMinter.createVoucher(1, metadata.url)`, is the 1 need to be an increment?

Comment: As you are using ERC721, You do. Or you can let the solidity code do the increment by removing tokenId as a parameter too. I hope you are checking whether the token is already minted before minting a token in your solidity contract, otherwise, there is a vulnerability of someone overriding metatada URL or even the price for that matter. 

Happy to help, have a nice day!!